# "I don't have the car tomorrow."

Tags: negation, possessives, future-tense, register

My friend and colleague doesn't have a car but he often uses his dad's car; so when he drives to work he most frequently picks me up and we go together.

Last night he texted me and said: "I don't have the car tomorrow so I can't pick you up. See you at work."

I believe something is wrong with the first sentence and wonder what a native speaker of English says to mean "I don't have the car tomorrow"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it as far as this native speaker is concerned. Consider "I don't have the time tomorrow".

Comment: I say that all the time. My husband and I share a car.

Comment: generally if a native speaker texts you something you don't understand, you should assume they did not make a mistake. nearly all native speakers have mastered conversational english.

Comment: @sgroves It is possible that the OP's friend is not a native English speaker. It could just be the language common between them.

Comment: wow, for some reason i thought OP mentioned his friend was a native speaker. my mistake.

Comment: @sgroves: My friend and I are both non-native speakers of English.

Comment: As a native speaker, it took me a while to figure out why I might *not* say "I don't have the car tomorrow." But @sgroves should bear in mind that I still might text him something like "I dont;' hsave the car tomorow" - while I have indeed long since mastered conversational English, keyboarding often eludes my clumsy fingers.

Answer (score 6):

I like user8543's analogy with "I don't have the time tomorrow". In this case you're seeing the present tense being used to talk about a schedule. Here's a slightly longer example which I hope provides some of the intuition for that usage.

> My wife and I share a car. She *has* the car on Mondays and Wednesdays, and I *have* the car on Tuesdays and Thursdays. Tomorrow is Wednesday, so I *don't have* the car.

You could also imagine a conversation like:

- Q: I'm going to need the car tomorrow, is that OK?
- A: Yes, you *can have* the car tomorrow.

Comment: The last part is pretty much the conversation we have every day.